# AWS Textract detecting different number of columns for multi page table

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, pdf, ocr, amazon-textract

I'm using AWS Textract to detect tables spanning multiple pages in a PDF document and convert these to a pandas data frame where I can do some further processing on them. At the moment though, the number of table columns per page is inconsistent. For example, the table has an 'A' column and a 'B' column but in some of the pages these are being merged to form an 'AB' column. As a result I can't concatenate the data frames into one data frame representing the full table as the number of columns is not consistent . I can solve this manually in pandas but it varies from document to document which columns are merged and would like to remove this step. The table dimensions/spacing don't seem to change from page to page in the PDF document.

Just wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and if there is any way to solve it.

I have followed the code from this github example https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-multipage-tables-processing/blob/main/Merge_Table_Notebook.ipynb but my output is never a fully merged data frame and instead only the data frames with the same number of columns are being merged

Comment: Is there a way to do this in AWS?